# How to distinguish between primary video and secondary video in starboard layer?

Tags: cobalt

For [Dual Playback Demo](https://ytlr-cert.appspot.com/2020/manual/dual_video.html) page

```
<video class="primary"></video>

<video class="secondary" muted autoplay loop src="//storage.googleapis.com/ytlr-cert.appspot.com/test-materials/media/manual/dual_video/secondary-video.mp4"
maximum-capabilities="width=432; height=240; framerate=15;"></video>
```

How to distinguish between primary video and secondary video while StarboardPlayer is being created?

In StarboardPlayer constructor

```
StarboardPlayer::StarboardPlayer(
    ... [parameters skipped]
    const std::string& max_video_capabilities)
```

max_video_capabilities string parameter is always empty on both primary and secondary, the page mentioned above doesn't use HTMLVideoElement.setMaxVideoCapabilities() to set max_video_capabilities parameter and following attribute in secondary video also not handled by HTMLMediaElement

```
maximum-capabilities="width=432; height=240; framerate=15;"
```

For resource limited system, minor resource allocated for secondary video during playback construction. For example, our system has only one resource which can be used in "punch out" output mode for primary video, so "decode to texture" output mode used in secondary video. After playback constructed, it seems not possible to change output mode dynamically? And memory resource also limited for secondary video.

So it's very important to distinguish between primary video and secondary video on resource limited embedded system, but it seems not possible in starboard layer and I don't want to modify code outside of starboard.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I noticed following code was added to dual_video.js. Now starboard layer can use max_video_capabilities string to determine whether it is secondary video or not.
Thank you :)

```
var secondaryVideo = document.querySelector('video.secondary');
secondaryVideo.setMaxVideoCapabilities('width=432; height=240; framerate=15;');
secondaryVideo.loop = true;
secondaryVideo.autoplay = true;
secondaryVideo.muted = true;
secondaryVideo.src = 'https://storage.googleapis.com/ytlr-cert.appspot.com/test-materials/media/manual/dual_video/secondary-video.mp4';
```